# Codeigniter Facebook Login fails

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, facebook-login

I tried several solutions from stackoverflow for this problem but no one helps, so I am opening a new one and hope someone can help me find a solution.

The **Facebook PHP API** is used for **Login to a Webportal**, but I do not get any user details after the user clicks on the login link and accepts the scope.
`$this->facebook->getUser()` always returns `0`.

The Facebook PHP files facebook.php, base_facebook.php and fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt are stored in `application/libraries/facebook/`.

### Facebook Configuration file application/config/development/facebook.php

```
$config['credentials'] = array(
  'appId' => 'the_app_id',
  'secret' => 'the_app_secret',
  'sharedSession' => true,
  'trustForwarded' => true,
  'cookie' => true
);

$config['login'] = array(
  'domain' => 'test.domain.com',
  'scope' => 'email',
  //this url is also defined in the facebook app for Login Action
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://test.domain.com/login/doLogin?facebook' 
);
```

### View application/view/index/loginForm.php

The view contains the link to the Facebook authentication controller.

```
...

<a href="<?= base_url('login/doLogin?facebook') ?>" class="btn facebook">
  Facebook Login
</a>

...
```

### Controller application/controllers/login.php

The function `doLogin` is checking for the requested login method and calling the corresponding function which handles the authentication.

```
public function doLogin() {
  $is_login = FALSE;

  //Facebook Login
  if ($this->input->get('facebook') !== FALSE) {

  //set get params to $_REQUEST Array for internal checks of the facebook library
  //because Codeigniter handles the input by it's own class input
  $_REQUEST = array(
    'code' => $this->input->get('code'),
    'state' => $this->input->get('state')
  );

  $is_login = $this->_facebook_login();
  } elseif (){
    //other Login Method
  }

  ... 
  //do some other stuff depending on $is_login e.g. redirects user to the correct url or show error
}

protected function _facebook_login() {
  $this->load->config('facebook');
  $fb_cred = $this->config->item('credentials');
  $this->load->library('facebook/facebook', $fb_cred);

  $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

  if ($user) {
    try {
      $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $user = null;
      log_message('error', $e);
      return FALSE;
    }
    var_dump($user_profile);
    return TRUE;
  }

  //User is not logged in via Facebook, so redirect him to the Facebook Login page
  $fb_login_conf = $this->config->item('login');
  $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($fb_login_conf);

  redirect($loginUrl);
}
```

### Login Steps

1. After clicking on the Facebook Login Link the user is redirected to Facebook.
2. There the user is logging in to Facebook and accepting the scope.
3. Then the user is redirected to the correct redirect URL.
4. The function `_facebook_login` should now get a token from the code and with the token the email of the user should be in `$user_profile`.

---

Edited Code according to curious_coder suggestion.
Now the browser returns an error `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)`

---

A try without looking for user

```
$this->load->config('facebook');
$fb_cred = $this->config->item('credentials');
$this->load->library('facebook/facebook', $fb_cred);

$user = $this->facebook->getUser();

try {
  $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
  var_dump($user_profile);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  $user = null;
  log_message('error', $e);
  return FALSE;
}
```

is throwing the following error message in Apache Log

```
[error] [client ***.***.***.***] CSRF state token does not match one provided., referer: http://test.domain.com/login/doLogin?facebook
```

and in Codeigniter Log

```
OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

The option `'sharedSession' => true` is causing the problem and after I removed it, I get the User data.

Answer (score 2):

According to me, the entire script is messed up. Here's what i suggest
1. Create a common function facebook_login in the controller
2. Whenever the user clciks "login with facebook", call the controller facebook_login

**Controller:**

```
public function facebook_login() {
  $this->load->config('facebook');
  $fb_cred = $this->config->item('credentials');
  $this->load->library('facebook/facebook', $fb_cred);

  $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

  if ($user) 
  {
    try {
          $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
          var_dump($user_profile);
    }catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
          $user = null;
          log_message('error', $e);
          return FALSE;
    }
  }else{
          $loginUrl = $this>facebook>getLoginUrl();
          header("Location:$loginUrl");
  }

}
```

**View:**

```
<a href="<?php echo(base_url()); ?>controller/facebook_login" class="btn facebook">
  Login with facebook
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my code/question accordingly. But now I get an error message from the browser telling `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)`. Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: thats because for some reason facebook is authenticating the user but `$user` is re-setting to zero. Resulting in infinite loop/redirect. One way to debug is to paste `try {
          $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
          var_dump($user_profile);
    }catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
          $user = null;
          log_message('error', $e);
          return FALSE;
    }` after `$user = $this->facebook->getUser();` and comment the `header("Location:$loginUrl");` in `else`. run the script and check the log and paste here the first 5 lines(line containing term error)

Comment: Hm did you mean move the try catch block before `$this->facebook->getUser();`?  I tested it and the first 5 lines containig the error in the log is `DEBUG - 2013-06-25 14:20:08 --> Form Validation Class Initialized
DEBUG  --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG  --> Helper loaded: date_helper
DEBUG  --> Config file loaded: application/config/development/facebook.php
ERROR  --> OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Comment: Not before `$this->facebook->getUser();` but after `$this->facebook->getUser();`. Just paste a copy. Don't alter the `try catch` present in `if($user)`.

Comment: Load the original solution and run the script. You will get `redirect error`. Then without closing the browser, paste the codes as instructed in previous comments and don't forget to comment the `header()`. Now again run the script in the old browser and paste the error.

Comment: Ok I updated it with the error messages I get in the Apache Log and the Codeigniter Log.

Comment: Try this script. http://pastebin.com/mKDapaCX and check whether you are getting output as zero

Comment: Yes your function is returning zero, after I commented the redirect out and reloaded the open page.

Comment: Ok I found the solution, the option `'sharedSession' => true` was causing this problem. When I removed it, I get the user. Thank you curious_coder for your help and tips.